# Difference between registry.byId and dom.byId in dojo? What is the advantage of using registry.byId?

Tags: dojo

What is the difference between `registry.byId` and `dom.byId` in dojo? What is the advantage of using `registry.byId`?

In the code below I'm using `dijit/registry` and `dojo/dom` for both my textbox (`#myTextBox3`) and my textbox node (`#textNode3`). Only two of them are providing results.

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(parser, dom, registry) {

    parser.parse();

    // Locate the JS object.
    var dibiWidget = registry.byId("myTextBox3");
    var dobiWidget = dom.byId("myTextBox3");
    var dibiDOM = registry.byId("textNode3");
    var dobiDOM = dom.byId("textNode3");


    dom.byId("textNode3").innerHTML = "registry.byId for widget id returned: " + dibiWidget + "<br>" +
        "dom.byId for widget id returned: " + dobiWidget + "<br>" +
        "registry.byId for dom id returned: " + dibiDOM + "<br>" +
        "dom.byId for dom id returned: " + dobiDOM + "<br>";
});
```

Answer (score 8):

These modules have a different usage. So there is no advantage of using `registry.byId()` (or `dom.byId()`) because they differ in use case.

### dijit/registry::byId()

The `dijit/registry` module main use is retrieving **widget** instances. Quoting the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/registry.html):

> dijit/registry stores a collection of all the dijit widgets within a
>   page. It is commonly used to retrieve a reference to a widget from a
>   related piece of data

### dojo/dom::byId()

The `dojo/dom` module on the other hand is just a module to access DOM nodes. Quoting the information of `byId()` on the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/dom.html):

> This is a simple alias to `document.getElementById`, which not only is
>   shorter to write, but fortunately works in all browsers. It turns a
>   domNode reference to some Node byId, or the same node reference if
>   passed a domNode.

### What does it mean?

The `registry.byId()` function will return an instance of your widget. This contains setters/getters and other stuff from the widget. This module should **only** be used to retrieve widgets, you cannot get a DOM node with it.

The `dom.byId()` function on the other hand will return the matching DOM node. You can only use it to retrieve a DOM node. A widget obviously also contains DOM nodes, but you should never directly access the DOM nodes of a widget because they're part of the internal structure of the widget (and may change).

When accessing a widget, **always** use `registry.byId()`. It provides APIs to access most DOM properties anyways.

---

### Your code

So, your code demonstrates the 4 possibilities here. Assuming `#myTextBox3` is a widget (for example of type `dijit/form/TextBox`) and `#textNode3` is a DOM node, the following will happen:

- `dibiWidget` will **work** because `#myTextBox3` is a widget. It will return a reference to that widget
- `dobiWidget` will **probably work**, because there is a DOM node behind every widget with the same ID (not required though). However, like I just explained, it's **not recommended** to use it.
- `dibiDom` will **not work** because there is no widget with ID `#textNode3`. This is just a simple DOM node.
- `dobiDom` will return a reference to the DOM node and will **work**.

I also made a small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VE5gn/) to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 4):

`dom.byId()` is just short for `document.getElementById(...)`. It returns a reference to the dom node.

`registry.byId(...)` returns a reference to a dojo widget that is contained in dojo's registry.

For example if you have `<div id='myDiv'></div>`, You can't call `registry.byId('myDiv')` here because it isn't a dojo widget (thus isn't in the dojo registry). You can call `dom.byId('myDiv')`.

Now if you had `<div id='myDiv' data-dojo-type='dijit/layout/ContentPane'></div>`, You can call both `dom.byId('myDiv')` and `registry.byId('myDiv')`. One gets you the dom node and the other gets you the dojo widget. Both will have different methods available to them but I generally favor `registry.byId(...)` if there is an overlap.

There isn't an advantage to using one or the other because they are both different things and used for different things.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/dom.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's really helpful. I have an image with id=something and I am using on(dom.byId("something"),"click",function() but instead of this , I tried to create a button <button id="something"><img src=...>and then on(registry.byId) but its not working. Can you tell me why it isn't working?

Comment: @user3587145 Make sure your tags have `data-dojo-type` if you are to use `registry.byId`. If it's a button it needs `dijit/form/Button`

Comment: Thank you for that...and is using registry advantageous in any way?I have been told to use only registry instead of dom.

Comment: @user3587145 Like I said in my answer, it's used for different things. Generally you'll want the widget reference so you will registry. But dom.byId has it's uses when you want the dom node, or if the element you are working with isn't a dojo widget. I also recommend formatting your question better so it meets the site's standards. That's why you're getting downvoted. Take a look here for hints. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you.I tried using the recommended ones and instead of dom.byId("something") , I used registry but still it doesn't work.

Comment: The **`registry`** is _only_ used when using **widgets**. If you're working with simple **DOM elements** (images, buttons, links, text, ...) you need to use the **`dojo/dom` module**. If you're working with autocomplete widgets, dialog widgets, button widgets, ... you should use the `dijit/registry` module.

Comment: Thanks.I am trying to implement filter functionality as in when user enters a value in the text box and clicks on the filter, the filtering effect takes place.For that, I am using registry.byId for the textboxes. I am new to dojo. So,I am pretty much confused.

Comment: It depends on what those text boxes are. Is the textbox just a plain `<input type="text"`/>` tag? Then you have to use **`dojo/dom`**. If you're using the module `dijit/form/TextBox`, then you have to use **`dijit/registry`**.