# how to code external onclick dojo dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog, buttonclick

How does one code to use an external js function for onclick handler in a button in an dialog with the ability to pass values from dijit.Dialog elements or must it be coded entirely inline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about what you're trying to say, but if you really want to call an external function, but you have no idea how to pass the parameters, you can still write an inline click handler that passes the arguments to your external function, for example:

```
registry.byId("myBtn").on("click", function() {
    var param1 = myDialog.get("param");
    externalFunction(param1);
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, however what is registry?  Should use dojo.() or even dijit.byId()?   What needs to preload for registry to work?  Finally when is the following pattern correct?

      <script type="dojo/on" data-dojo-event="click" data-dojo-args="evt">
        require(["dojo/dom"], function(dom){
        });
        </script>

Comment: `dijit.byId()` is the same as `registry.byId()`, but it's the >1.7 syntax. About the differences between the 2 I would like to redirect you to another answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376417/difference-between-registry-byid-and-dom-byid-in-dojo-what-is-the-advantage-of/23494864#23494864 In addition, `dijit.byId()` is the same as `registry.byId()` (`dijit/registry`), just like `dojo.byId()` is the same as `dom.byId()` (`dojo/dom`).